# Invisible unordered list (and there's no CSS rules on it)?

Tags: html, css

This page: http://alexchen.info/brianfunshine/2011/04/suscipit-lobortis/
has the the following output:

(I'm using Firefox 4.0)

```
                    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Fred</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Killin Brain Cells</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Prodigal Son</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">The Cramper</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3 Sheets To The Wind (What&#8217;s My Name)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">My Oedipus Complex</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Rollin&#8217; On The Island</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Rain Check</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Trippin With Dick Vitale</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">T.V. Dinner</a></li>
</ul>
```

The unordered list doesn't have any style, but it is invisible!

reference picture:

[image]

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your div with class `.content-block-4`, which contains the list, has `height: 309px` and `overflow: hidden`, which combine to hide any content in the div that would normally appear lower than 309 pixels.

Easiest thing to do is probably remove the `height` on that div.

Answer (score 0):

its being blocked by that image with the giraffe:

use firebug and delete than element and you'll see what I mean

```
<a href="http://alexchen.info/brianfunshine/2011/04/suscipit-lobortis/" title="Permalink to Suscipit lobortis" rel="bookmark"><img width="308" height="277" src="http://alexchen.info/brianfunshine/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/03.png" class="attachment-large wp-post-image" alt="03" title="03"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The div the unordered list in has a height set (of 309px) and the 'overflow' set to 'hidden'